# How to add inheritance of mongoengine.Document into an existing class

Tags: python-3.x, mongoengine

I've got a class `Book` which should inherit from `mongoengine.Document`:

```
from mongoengine import Document
from mongoengine import StringField


class Book(Document):
    title = StringField()
    author = StringField()
    shelf = IntField()
    room = IntField()

    def __init__(self,
                 title=None,
                 author=None,
                 position_tag=None,
                 *args, **kwargs):
        super(Document, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.title = title
        self.author = author

        if position_tag:
            # position tag is room#shelf
            self.room, self.shelf = position_tag.split("#")

    @property
    def id(self):
        """Custom id of the document, I want to avoid autogenerated ObjectID()"""
        return f'{self.room}-{self.shelf}-{self.title}'

    def get_price_of_all_books_in_corporation(self, author):
        pass

test_book = Book(title="Some_Title", author="Mark Twain", positon_tag="205.1#5")
test_book.save()  # should be saved with id "205.1-5-Some_Title"
test_book.get_price_of_all_books_in_corporation('William Shakespeare')
```

I would like to use objects of Book also elsewhere in my project and therefore need to add support for additional parameters such as `position_tag` when instantiating a new book object. Somehow this example still produces documents with a random `ObjectID`. I've also tried adding a class field `id = StringField(primary_key=True)`, which didn't solve the problem for me. In general, is this the desired approach? I would like to add more functionalities to the `Book` object itself to allow direct use of the loaded mongo data.